# sobolev space-equivalence of scalar product

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, inner-products

Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n).$ Why the equation $\Delta u - u = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ admits a unique solution $u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

2- Prove that there exist a constant $C \geq 0$ that $||u||_{H^1} \leq C ||f||_{L^2}$.

3- Prove that there exist a constant $M \geq 0$ that for all $u \in H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we have $||u||_{H^2} \leq M (||u||_{L^2})$.

4- We assume that $$\sum_{i,j=1=1,\dots,n} \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2} \overline{\dfrac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_j^2}} dx + \lambda \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u \overline{v} dx$$
represente an scalar product to $H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $\lambda > 0.$

Prove that this scalar product is equivalent to the classical scalar product to $H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$

My problem is the question 4. How we can prove the equivalence of this two scalar product?
Thank's.

Answer (score 2):

One can prove (using the Fourier transform, e.g.) that 
$$ \lVert u\rVert_{H^2} \le C(\lVert u \rVert_{L^2} + \lVert \Delta u\rVert_{L^2}).$$ 
(This might be what you meant in item 3 - what's currently written is trivially true.)

Then for (4) you want to show that the usual norm on $H^2$ is equivalent to the norm
$$ \lVert u\rVert_{\tilde{H}^2}^2 := \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lvert \Delta u\rvert^2 + \lvert u \rvert^2$$
i.e. that there exist constants $C_1,C_2>0$ so that
$$ C_1 \lVert u\rVert_{\tilde{H}^2}^2  \le \lVert u\rVert_{H^2}^2 \le C_2 \lVert u\rVert_{\tilde{H}^2}^2.$$
The second inequality follows from above (from 3, probably), and the first follows easily from the estimate
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lvert \Delta u\rvert^2 \le C \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{ij}\lvert \partial_i \partial_j u\rvert^2$$

Comment: Any one can help me please

Comment: I don't understand how we prove the first inequality

Comment: You can use the Fourier transform for an easy proof.  If you don't like that, you can also use integration by parts to prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{ij}\lvert \partial_i \partial_j u\rvert^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lvert \Delta u\rvert^2$ for smooth functions and then use a density argument.

Comment: I have two questions: the classical norm on $H^2(\mathbb{R^n})$ is $||u||^2_{H^2}=||\Delta u||^2_{L^2} + ||\nabla u||^2_{L^2} + ||u||^2_{L^2}$ or $||u||^2_{H^2}=||\Delta u||^2_{L^2} + ||u||^2_{L^2}$? 2- with integration by parts we obtain an equality, not an inequality how we obtain the inequality to prove the equivalence?

Comment: The usual definition also has $\nabla u$ (your first expression).  You can also IBP to estimate the $L^2$ norm of $\nabla u$ in terms of those of $\Delta u$ and $u$.

Comment: please i don't understand. Can you explicit this point (prove the second inequality)

Comment: To prove the first inequality, i.e. there exist a constant $c_2 > 0$ such that $||u||_* \leq c_2 ||u||_{H^2}$ then, we have $$\sum_{i,j=1,...n} \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2} . \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_j^2} dx| \leq \sum_{i,j=1,...,n} ||\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i}||_{L^2} ||\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_j^2}||_{L^2}$$ by holder inequality, then by Young inequality,

Comment: $$\sum_{i,j=1,...n} \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2} . \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_j^2} dx| \leq \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j=1,...n} (||\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}||^2_{L^2} + ||\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_j^2}||^2_{L^2}) \leq \sum_{i,j=1}^n (||\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}||^2_{L^2} + ||\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_j^2}||^2_{L^2})$$

Comment: and i don't know how to finish to show the equivalence

Comment: Any one can help me please

Comment: please how can use the estimate $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lvert \Delta u\rvert^2 \le C \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{ij}\lvert \partial_i \partial_j u\rvert^2$$ to prove the inequality?